# Clicking on a URL opens it in the default browser, but it does not always bring the browser window to the front. Why is that?

Tags: windows, windows-8, browser

Clicking on URLs usually works fine for me, but sometimes it suddenly stops working. That is, if I click on a link in some application, like Skype, then the URL is opened in the default browser, but the browser window is not brought to the front. It stays behind other windows.

What can be the reason of this? That is, that it's working fine everywhere and then it stops working for some reason and I have to switch to the browser window manually to see the page which has been opened there.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what causes it, but a Windows restart fixed it. Simply restarting Explorer was not enough.